# Returning N random items from smaller original list

Tags: python, random

I'm surprised I haven't found a way to do this without a loop, since it seems like a pretty standard problem.
Working in python, 
I have  `colors = ["red","green","blue"]` and I'd like to put these elements into a list of length N in a random order.   Right now I'm using:

```py
import random
colors = ["red","green","blue"]
otherList = []

for i in range (10):  # N=10 
    otherList.append(random.choice(colors))
```

This returns: `otherList = ["red","green","green","green","blue","green","red","green","green","blue"]`, which is exactly what I want. I'm just looking for a more idiomatic way of doing this? Any ideas? It looked like random.sample might have been the answer, but I didn't see anything in the documentation that fit exactly my needs.

Comment: You could use a list comprehension ... `[random.choice(colors) for i in range(10) ]`

Comment: I'm guessing that extra backtick is a mistake in copying and pasting?

Comment: @mgilson, hey that's awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[random.choice(colors) for i in range(10)] #xrange for python2 compatability
```

Or `random.sample()` through some gymnastics:

```py
nrandom = 10
random.sample( colors*(nrandom//len(colors)+1), nrandom )
```

Although I don't think that is better than the list-comprehension ...

Comment: This fails if len(colors) < 10. sample was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @wagras -- Yeah, I figured that out when I tried it.  I've updated.  surprisingly the docs don't mention that restriction...

Comment: Oh, you mean the second sample? In that case, the docs say "Return a k length list of **unique** elements chosen from the population sequence."

Comment: @NiklasB. -- `random.sample(colors,10)` fails with a `ValueError`.

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, figured that out :P See my comment above

Comment: @NiklasB. -- Thanks for pointing that out.  In that case, my second answer also doesn't work. (I've removed it)

Comment: In fact [it would](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample): "If the population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible selection in the sample.". Also, we can use `xrange` in Python 2, which is faster than `range`

Comment: @NiklasB. -- you're right about `xrange` vs `range`.  Generally in my solutions I like to post code which I know will run no matter what version of python the OP is using -- But I've updated with a comment.

Comment: You're right, that's a pretty important argument. I've probably been brainwashed by #python

Comment: @mgilson, I never fully grokked the behavior of `sample` until I looked at the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l290), which I found quite enlightening.

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughness. I am using the first solution and aspiring to understand the second.

Comment: @wagras -- I don't really like the second very much.  Basically, when you multiply a list by a number (N), you concatenate it with itself N times.  e.g. `['red','blue','green']*2` yields `['red','blue','green','red','blue','green']`.  So I use integer division to make sure that we have a list that is longer than the desired output list and take a sample from that list.  The problem with that solution is that it only works with simple sequences (`list`,`tuple`,`str`) and not with more complex objects like generators (which is why the first is better -- that and it's more easily understood).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
>>> colors = ["red","green","blue"]
>>> [random.choice(colors) for i in range(10)]
['green', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```